# Delete multiple rows from a Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to delete from a database all  the rows in which a particular field contains a particular value. For example I need to cancel all the rows where field name = "Ricky".
What should I do to implement it. i have found:
    MyDB.delete(TABLE_NAME,"name", "Ricky"); 
but it says that the method delete is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)...what to modify?
In this way this method check all the rows of the db or I have to implement a for cicle for every row?

Comment: `DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE name = 'Ricky'`?

Comment: ya just use the rowquery

Comment: But in this way it check all the rows with name = 'Ricky' or it does't once?

Comment: It will delete from that `TABLE_NAME` all rows that have `Ricky` at column name `name`. It will delete all the rows that meet that condition. If you dont use any condition, `DELETE` will delete all data from your `TABLE_NAME`, so use it careful.